# XEP-0191 not working with ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

In my iOS chat application I am using ejabberd server to work with XMPP framework. I am trying to block a user using XEP-191. It is sending all the stanza correctly and I can see the user, I am blocking in the blocking list. But still I can see their presence, send message etc:

[_id: E8C458AB-DFC0-4C11-B91F-CF8FAB1911CA, _xmlns: jabber:client, __name: iq, _type: result, _to: user1@localhost/22895732401453270657994362, _from: user1@localhost, blocklist: {
    "_xmlns" = "urn:xmpp:blocking";
    item =     {
        "_jid" = "user2@localhost";
    };
}]

I have also tried XEP-0016, thats also not working.

Comment: How did you configure it ? What does your configuration file looks like ?

Comment: mod_blocking: {} # requires mod_privacy
 ## mod_multicast: {}
  mod_offline: 
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  ## mod_pres_counter:
  ##   count: 5
  ##   interval: 60
  mod_privacy: {}

Comment: Can you please update your post ? Yaml is spacing sensitive, so hard to tell if it is good from a SO comment.

Comment: Can you also check the log files and check if you see error message in there ?